# 21.04 UEFI boot fails: Could not create MOKlistXRT: Out of resources

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm getting the errors

```
Could not create MOKlistXRT: Out of resources
```

and

```
something has gone seriously wrong: import_MOK_state(): Out of resources
```

when trying to boot 21.04 clean installed from a flash drive onto a Dell Latitude E6410 laptop with A17 BIOS in UEFI mode.

I saw the similar previous post referring to "18.04 UEFI boot fails" and tried the solution given there, but in my Latitude's A17 UEFI settings, "General > Boot Sequence > Add Boot Option > File System List" only shows the EFI and msdata partitions with no filenames visible.

There's no way to browse for grubx64.efi as suggested there. Entering EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi under "File Name" doesn't help. I've verified that the file is present at that location.

Does anyone know the solution to this?
[image: Add Boot Option image:]

Comment: If the error is about MOK state try disabling Secure Boot before anything else

Comment: How? That's not a BIOS option and the OS isn't booting.

Comment: Actually it's UEFI (still called "BIOS" incorrectly by many users and manufacturers) and Secure Boot *is* part of it. It may have a different name though. I suggest you edit your question first and foremost for **readability** (use code tags for error codes {}, make proper sentences and paragraphs) but also to add hardware specification and brand/model). Meanwhile also update UEFI ("BIOS"), even when new most laptops often need it.

Comment: Dell still uses the term BIOS, and in my laptop's case, the firmware has both legacy and UEFI modes. Neither mode has a setting for Secure Boot. The only boot settings are for boot sequence and fastboot. The firmware is already at the latest available revision (A17).

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-ag/000133480/uefi-and-secure-boot-faqs

Comment: The second step on that document is not relevant to my Dell E6410, as the A17 firmware has neither a "Boot Tab" nor any other reference to Secure Boot. I can only conclude it doesn't support the function. Both Kubuntu 12.10 and Windows 10 Pro (build 21364) boot up on the machine with no errors, which is why I wonder what's preventing (K)ubuntu 21.04 from doing so.

Comment: Then please do your own research, read your user's manual, check Dell forum, etc.

Comment: Or just enable Legacy and it should have no problem. There was no mention of the model in the original text and the UEFI boot suggests a faily recent machine but that model is very old, early UEFI. Probably better to just install the old way.

Comment: I have similar problem on Samsung New Series 9 laptop. On mine it says "Failed to set MoKListXRT: Out of resources" and "Could not create MoKListXRT: Out of resouces". I just upgraded from 20.10. When I boot I get these two lines on the screen. However, grub still works. If I wait for 10 seconds, it boots into default, as I have 10 seconds timeout. I can also press arrow down and enter and select other GRUB entries. The problem is I cannot see GRUB and what I am selecting. Fortunately I know the menu contents, so two clicks down is Windows, and three entering BIOS settings.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: in the case of my Dell E6410, the solution was indeed to use grubx64.efi instead of shimx64.efi, as suggested elsewhere. I discovered that the catch on that machine is that under "Boot Sequence/Add Boot Option" the file name has to be entered with backslashes as \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi rather than with forward slashes as in the image on my previous post.

Comment: Worked for me (Dell E6510). Dont forget to move the new boot option to the top of the list though.

Comment: Can confirm this works on my Dell OptiPlex 390 SFF running Debian. You can browse to the `grubx64.efi` file via the `...` menu from `Boot Sequence` -> `Add Boot Option`. It's found at `\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi`. Hit `Apply` and then `Exit`. Debian should then boot normally. 

FWIW, if you need to get into the OS & don't have time for the above, you should also be able to to legacy boot into Debian via the `F12` menu.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error on Thinkpad T430 after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04.
It affects several users, so I have reported the bug on launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1924605

One solution is to delete `Mok*` variables in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. The files are immutable but even after using `chattr -i` and `rm -rf` commands they do not delete.

Comment: This answer seems to be the right one, but I still have no success, because I cannot delete Mok* efivars. :-( I get "Invalid argument" error.

Comment: Before finding my own solution, I used a terminal from a live CD to check the contents of /sys/firmware/efi/efivars on the affected machine only to find there were no Mok* variables listed there.

Comment: I have the same issue on my Thinkpad x230. I cant delete the efivars no matter what setting i use in BIOS or if i remove the -i.
Grub menu doesnt show, only show the error "could not create MokListXRT: Out of Resources" but it does boot to the system afterwards.
From discussions on the bugtracker i seems to be an issue with signing stuff not beeing updated due to realife covid issues making the blacklist too long for the efi space on the mainboard.

Comment: @k1l I saw that. I'm not sure I buy the COVID excuse. Linux development has always been decentralized. They got sloppy & now users are winding up with unbootable machines. 

Have you tried Al Preston's EFI path solution (see above.) I'm not sure if Lenovo BIOSes even allow that (all my Lenovos run Windows 10.)

Comment: it works again for me. looks like it was fixed in the shim(-signed) pacakges.