do-release-upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 crashed during restart. import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
While doing do-release-upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, this system encountered an issue during restart(i.e. after installing 24.04 was completed). How do I recover from this issue? The upgrade procedure is given by nixCraft.

Below is the EFI boot screen:


Please fresh install (use live USB to backup data in the home folder). Too many people are facing similar issues.

This looks like a secure boot issue. If you turn off secure-boot I suspect it would boot normally. I suspect that your WIN boot (in one pic)  has disabled your grub from starting with an SBAT increment. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1523438/verifying-shim-sbat-data-failed-security-policy-violation for how to fix this. also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333492/21-04-uefi-boot-fails-could-not-create-moklistxrt-out-of-resources for more info.

@david The same msg still appears with Secure Boot turned off.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I can't even do a fresh install using a live USB, even though the usb thumbdrive is prioritise for booting and all partitions in the system M.2 SATA SSD have been removed. The same error msg appears when booting using live USB.

This answer by Shai Coleman on Unix & Linux solved my issue. All credit goes to him.

The solution for me was clearing the EFI variables and then disabling
secure boot.
On my Asus X556 laptop, I followed the following steps, but they'll
vary for each computer:

Press F2 during boot to enter the BIOS
Press F7 to enabled Advanced Mode
Security > Secure Boot > Secure Boot Control: Enabled. You need to enable Secure Boot for access the key management.
Security > Secure Boot > Key Management: Reset to Setup Mode to clear all the variables and keys. It should show "No Key" multiple times.
Security > Secure Boot > Secure Boot Control: Disabled. Secure boot must be disabled because there are no valid keys.
Save and exit


